# Export Oracle Result to Excel using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My desired result from the below PS script is to end up with the result in a CSV or XLS file, which every is the easiest..

I run the below Powershell command, which gives me the desired results - so far so good.

I'm stuck on how to get this information into Excel, so that I can then use this for reporting..

```
$OracleCommand = "SELECT user_info.directory_auth_id, 
    user_info.display_name,
      chat_account.chat_system_id,
        chat_account.login_id,
          chat_account.account_id,
            chat_account.is_deleted,
              chat_system.server_address"
$OracleCommand += " FROM user_info"
$OracleCommand += " INNER JOIN chat_account ON chat_account.user_id = user_info.entity_id"
$OracleCommand += " INNER JOIN chat_system ON chat_system.system_id = chat_account.chat_system_id"
$OracleCommand += " WHERE user_info.directory_auth_id ="
$OracleCommand += "'" + $User + "'"

Invoke-OracleCommand -OracleConnectionString (Get-Content 'ConnectionString.txt') `
-QueryString $OracleCommand |
```

Do I need to loop through the results and export to csv....

Thanks,
boardman

Answer (score 0):

I'd go ahead and export to CSV as that makes the rest of the process easier. This code will let you import the CSV:

```
$csv = "C:\myData.csv"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $Show
$wbObj = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
$dataSheet = $wbObj.Worksheets.Item(1)
$qryConn = ("TEXT;" + $csv)
$qryDest = $dataSheet.Range("A1")
$conn = $dataSheet.QueryTables.Add($qryConn,$qryDest)
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).TextFileCommaDelimiter = $true
$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).TextFileParseType  = 1
[void]$dataSheet.QueryTables.item($conn.name).Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I'll have a look at the code, see if I can make it work..